# Same version of Docker installed on two computers, but the same docker-compose file works only on one of them

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The computers in question are my PC and my laptop.

Their OS: Kubuntu LTS edition up to date with all updates (both)

Docker version: 20.10.24, build 297e128

Docker-compose version: v2.17.2

Context: Initially I developed the project on the PC with the versions stated, git cloned it on the laptop saw the error, tried to fix it couldn't I then replicated the exact version of docker and docker-compose from my PC to my laptop but that still didn't help.

Error:

```
WARN[0000] The "PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'Ports': No port specified: :<empty>
```

The docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./dockerConfig/postgres-dev-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql 
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:6-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis_volume:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  adonis_app:
    container_name: adonis_app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    build:
      context: .
      target: dependencies
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - PG_HOST=postgres
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    command: dumb-init node ace serve --watch --node-args="--inspect=0.0.0.0"

volumes:
  postgres_volume:
  redis_volume:
```

And the Dockerfile for my app:

```
ARG NODE_IMAGE=node:16.13.1-alpine

FROM $NODE_IMAGE AS base
RUN apk --no-cache add dumb-init
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && chown node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
USER node
RUN mkdir tmp

FROM base AS dependencies
COPY --chown=node:node ./package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY --chown=node:node . .

FROM dependencies AS build
RUN node ace build --production

FROM base AS production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=$PORT
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
COPY --chown=node:node ./package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --production
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /home/node/app/build .
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [ "dumb-init", "node", "server.js" ]
```

If the solution is to update the files/version that is ok with me I just want to be able to work on it both at home and when I'm away from home.

Comment: Try `env | grep PORT` on both machines - I wonder if it is set on one machine and not the other. Or, perhaps, are you supplying it in the `docker compose` command? How do you start your container(s)?

Comment: @halfer Just the same `docker-compose up` you were right about the env being different I forgot I had to recreate the .env file as per the answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that the `- ${PORT}:${PORT}` variable in the .env file could not be found.

When you git cloned the project over to the other system, might the .env file have been part of your .gitignore file and thus wasn't copied over?

Comment: Yes, this was it. I kept thinking the error was that somehow the ports needed to be defined differently but actually I had forgotten to create the .env on my laptop (it's in the gitignore so it wasn't copied over via git)